# error running python manage.py on ubuntu

Tags: django, python-3.4

Please help, I am fairly new to django. 
I am using  virtualenv (which has django installed) I have used this command to create a new project
django-admin startproject projectname
and consequently used the code
cd projectname.
But when I run python manage.py
I get this error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
>     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
> ImportError: No module named 'django'
> ```

this is how my `manage.py` file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "firstdjango.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you did it, but did you activate your virtualenv before running manage.py runserver ?

Comment: Does django show up in your list of installed packages? type `pip freeze` to find out.

Comment: If you are running manage.py from inside an IDE make sure to activate the correct virtual environment in your IDE. For example for Pycharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/adding-existing-virtual-environment.html

Comment: Yes I have activated my environment.

Comment: Yes I have Django in my list and I am not using an IDE

Answer (score 0):

Install virtual environment in your system

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

Create virtual environment

```
virtualenv envirnment_name
```

Activate virtual environment by following command

```
source envirnment_name/bin/activate
```

Install django in virtual environment

```
pip install django
```

And then run your django server

```
pyhton manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you are working on the virtualenv that you created using `workon your_virtual_env`.

Second, try the `pip freeze > requirements.txt` so you can check the installed packages. The file should have a structure like this:

```
Django == 1.10.2
SomePackage == 1.2.3
SomeOtherPackage == 1.2.3
```

You can verify that the Django package is installed this way.